# Does Groovy have log4j vulnerability?

Tags: groovy, log4j

I'm using Groovy and was asked if Groovy (version 3) has the Log4J vulnerabilty, and I said I would check.

I have version `3.0.7` based on `groovy --version` command which gives this output:
`Groovy Version: 3.0.7 JVM: 17.0.1 Vendor: Red Hat, Inc. OS: Linux`

A simple search on the internet and stackoverflow did not find the answer.

My research says no it is not affected because of the following:

- No log4j Jar files found
- the Groovy command (in Linux) is a shell script, so no Log4J there.
- No imports of the library
- Two wrapper files that likely delegate to whatever version of log4j the user has selected.
- Groovy is basically a compiler that converts Groovy or Java code into JVM code.  It is not a server side application, and has no background processes listening for incoming requests.

## My Research (how I decided)

This is how I came up with my conclusion that Groovy does not have the log4j vulnerability.

The package I examined was `apache-groovy-sdk-3.0.9.zip` downloaded from this page Groovy website page. https://groovy.apache.org/download.html#distro

#### Log4J Vulnerability is explained several places

I'll point to the Apache's website https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html which describes it.  But basically, an application that uses log4j is running and allows end user input to be logged.  Since Groovy is not an application that does not take incoming internet connections, it's a compiler/transpiler it doesn't have the vulnerability.

But I continued ...

#### No log4j jar files (based on find)

```
find . -type f | sort | grep -i jar | grep -i log4j
```

No output, so no log4j files jar files embedded in the Groovy distribution.

#### No log4j imports in source code

```
find . -type f | grep '\.java$' | xargs grep -l import | grep -i 'import.*log4j'
```

#### Two log4j source files that are wrappers (based on inspection of code)

```
find . -type f | sort | grep -i log4j
./doc/html/api/groovy/util/logging/Log4j2.html
./doc/html/api/groovy/util/logging/Log4j2.Log4j2LoggingStrategy.html
./doc/html/api/groovy/util/logging/Log4j.html
./doc/html/api/groovy/util/logging/Log4j.Log4jLoggingStrategy.html
./doc/html/gapi/groovy/util/logging/Log4j2.html
./doc/html/gapi/groovy/util/logging/Log4j.html
./src/src/main/java/groovy/util/logging/Log4j2.java    <<<< SEE THIS
./src/src/main/java/groovy/util/logging/Log4j.java     <<<< SEE THIS
./src/src/test/groovy/util/logging/Log4j2Test.groovy
./src/src/test/groovy/util/logging/Log4jTest.groovy
```

If anyone can find other references on the internet that state that Groovy is not vulnerable please let me know.

Comment: "Groovy is basically a compiler that converts Groovy or Java code into JVM code." - That is a mischaracterization of Groovy.  Groovy is more than a compiler.  Groovy contains a compiler.  There are a good number of libraries that Groovy depends on.

Answer (score 2):

> Does Groovy have log4j vulnerability?

No, but one could definitely write a Groovy application which introduces the vulnerability.

I have created a default empty Groovy 3.0.7 project and generated a dependency report.  Below is the default runtime classpath:

```
runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
\--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.7
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant:3.0.7
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     |    +--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.10.9
     |    |    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.10.9
     |    +--- org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.10.9
     |    |    \--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.10.9 (*)
     |    +--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.10.9
     |    +--- org.apache.ant:ant-antlr:1.10.9
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-groovydoc:3.0.7
     |         +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     |         +--- com.github.javaparser:javaparser-core:3.17.0
     |         +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:3.0.7
     |         |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     |         |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:3.0.7
     |         |         \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     |         \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-docgenerator:3.0.7
     |              +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:3.0.7 (*)
     |              +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     |              \--- com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:1.12.1
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-astbuilder:3.0.7
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-cli-picocli:3.0.7
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     |    \--- info.picocli:picocli:4.5.2
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-console:3.0.7
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:3.0.7 (*)
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-swing:3.0.7
     |         \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-datetime:3.0.7
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-docgenerator:3.0.7 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-groovydoc:3.0.7 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-groovysh:3.0.7
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:3.0.7 (*)
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-console:3.0.7 (*)
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:3.0.7 (*)
     |    \--- jline:jline:2.14.6
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-jmx:3.0.7
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:3.0.7
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-jsr223:3.0.7
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-macro:3.0.7
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-nio:3.0.7
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-servlet:3.0.7
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:3.0.7 (*)
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:3.0.7 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:3.0.7
     |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-swing:3.0.7 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:3.0.7 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-test:3.0.7
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     |    \--- junit:junit:4.13.1
     |         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-test-junit5:3.0.7
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0
     |    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.0
     |    |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0 (c)
     |    |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0 (c)
     |    |    |    +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.7.0 (c)
     |    |    |    +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.7.0 (c)
     |    |    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.0 (c)
     |    |    +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
     |    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.0
     |    |         \--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.0 (*)
     |    +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.7.0
     |    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.7.0
     |    |         +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.0 (*)
     |    |         +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
     |    |         \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.0 (*)
     |    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0
     |         +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.0 (*)
     |         +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.7.0 (*)
     |         \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-testng:3.0.7
     |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.7
     |    \--- org.testng:testng:7.3.0
     |         \--- com.beust:jcommander:1.78
     \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:3.0.7 (*)
```

Comment: Just curious.  What were the commands you used to create the project and the report

Comment: "What were the commands you used to create the project and the report" - One way to do it is using `gradle init`, adding the `project-reports` plugin and running `./gradlew dR`.

Comment: FYI... If you do that you may want to remove the example dependences that `gradle init` adds to the default generated `build.gradle` because those will contribute other items to the dependency graph that don't represent dependencies of Groovy.

Comment: "If anyone can find other references on the internet that state that Groovy is not vulnerable please let me know." - Are you looking for any particular kinds of references?  We don't have a published list of vulnerabilities that don't affect Groovy.  If you can clarify what you are looking for, we can help.

Comment: I was looking for something like https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html which lists vulnerabilities related to Apache Log4j, but since there are none, this question likely answered with `there is no page that describes the the log4j vulnerabilities because there are none.`

Comment: @PatS If the question is "Does Groovy have log4j vulnerability?", I think the answer is no.  If the question is is there a web page that says that lists the log4j vulnerabilities that Groovy has, I don't think there is a list, for the reason you cited.